# PHP how to upload xml file to server

Tags: php, xml, file-upload

I made simple function:

```
    function get($field, $dir = 'dir/') {
            $file_tmp = $_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'];
            $file_name = $_FILES[$field]['name'];
            $file_size = $_FILES[$field]['size'];
            $ext = explode(".", $file_name);
            $ext = $ext[1];
            if ($ext != 'xml') {
                if (is_uploaded_file($file_tmp)) {
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $dir . $file_name);
                    echo "file: 
                      $file_name size:  
                      $file_size done !
                      ";
                } else {
                    echo "Possible file upload attack: ";
                    echo "filename '" . $file_tmp . "'.";
                }
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $dir . $file_name);
                echo "file: 
                      $file_name size:  
                      $file_size done !
                      ";
            }
        }
```

Function upload files to server (eg. .jpg, .gif), but when I try to upload a .xml something goes wrong and file do not upload. Why is that?

Comment: What does "do not upload" mean? It doesn't show up in `$_FILES`? You get a PHP error? You get an Apache error? You get "done" but file is not there?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "Something" that goes wrong?

Comment: Sorry... Yes it's done but file is not in directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this and then check what's going on:

```
function get( $field, $dir = 'dir/' )
{
    $file_tmp = $_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'];
    $file_name = $_FILES[$field]['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES[$field]['size'];
    $ext = explode( ".", $file_name );
    $ext = $ext[1];

    if ( $ext != 'xml' ) {
        if ( is_uploaded_file( $file_tmp ) ) {
            move_uploaded_file( $file_tmp, $dir . $file_name );
            echo "file: $file_name size: $file_size done ! ";
        } else {
            echo "Possible file upload attack: ";
            echo "filename '" . $file_tmp . "'.";
        }
    } else {
        if ( is_uploaded_file( $file_tmp ) ) {
            move_uploaded_file( $file_tmp, $dir . $file_name );
            echo "file: $file_name size: $file_size done !";
        } else {
            echo "There was a porblem, check error.log";
        }
    }
}
```

And also, the default limit on wamp server is 2MB for file uploads, try increasing that value.

Comment: I get "There was a porblem, check error.log". Is some serwer problem?

Comment: I have no idea how can I check this on WAMP serwer... I go to "wamp\logs" and there is "POST /test/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1944... Whether it is?

Comment: Are you sure you have `log_errors = On` in your configuration? And also, does your configuration allow XML files to be uploaded? How is big is the XML file, you are trying to upload?

Comment: Yes... this is the problem, file size. XML has 7,5 MB and limit on serwer was 2 MB. I change this, now works fine. Thanks for help :)